# How to see the oldest Chatter posts in an environment?

Tags: chatter, administration

After many years, when you are leaving a project which you started, you perhaps would want to see the first few Chatter posts to remind yourself how it all started. The long way to do this would be to just keep scrolling down on the *All Company* Chatter. It's nearly impossible when it's years of posts. I tried entering the calendar year (E.g., 2011) in the *All Company* feed search (not global search), but this doesn't search the post dates. Can anyone think of any UI trick before resorting to Apex?